# How does one initialize the tag manager using react-gtm-module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-gtm-module

I am converting a standard html/css/javascript website into a React PWA. I am having issues initializing Google Tag Manager using react-gtm-module.

The following snippet is from the original working html site.

```
<code>
script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxx871634"> /script
</code>
```

The following React snippet is located in the App.js file:

```
<code>
import GTagManager from 'react-gtm-module';
GTagManager.initialize({gtmId: 'AW-xxx871634'});
class App extends React.Component {
</code>
```

The Tag Assistant tool flags the following error:

```
<code>
script async="" src=""https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=AW-959871634&gtm_auth=&gtm_preview=&gtm_cookies_win=x"">/script

Invalid or missing account ID?
HTTP response code indicates tag failed to fire: Status 404. This could be due to an empty or un-published container.
</code>
```

I get the same error locally or after running 'npm run build' and uploading to the host web server.

I also get the same error with the following:

```
<code>
import GTagManager from 'react-gtm-module';
class App extends React.Component {
...
componentDidMount(){
GTagManager.initialize({gtmId: 'AW-xxx871634'});
...
</code>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I incorrectly initialized using the conversion ID versus the Google Tag Manager container ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use containerId in place of gtmid
GTagManager.initialize({containerId: 'AW-xxx871634'});